Frontend library for in-page responsive chat, independent of the backend
I need to find a frontend library so I can easily include a front-end chat to any of my web pages.
Purpose:

Make the user able to dialog with automated systems, so we can make offers, give them wizards and help to choose between options, guide with the page navigation, etc.

Objective requirements:

Installable via yarn
Compatible with symfony-created pages
MUST SUPPORT BUTTONS to facilitate the user to write without writing
Must be responsive
Backend independent: able to contact via REST with our own chat-server (we may do the protocol they want)
IDK if there's a standard protocol for this. If it exists, desireably follows standard protocols.
Must be open source
Must be maintained. Last commit cannot be 2 years ago.

Reference:

Similar to this one https://github.com/huggingface/chat-ui but without the huggingface stuff.
Similar to this but newer https://github.com/riversun/chatux - This one is updated 2 years ago.

In short:

I'll do all the chat backend. I only want to save some time with the css and javascript.

